# Retrieve existing object into variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

On my page I initially declare variable `var as` which creates an object through plugin using createAll... I'm referring to this plugin: http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/docs/

In order for plugin to work this object needs to be created. So after that I load some contact through ajax and plugin needs to be applied to this new content, so again I create this `var as` to create object, however now there are two similar objects on a page which conflict. I would like to know it there is a way where I can make `var as` that gets created after ajax call equal to existing object on a page?

I tried looking at what's inside `var as` by doing `alert(as);` This returns `[Object object]`

**EDIT**

This is what gets printed out with console log (This is original, first object)

```
Object

duration: 1
element: HTMLAudioElement
loadStartedCalled: false
loadedPercent: 0
mp3: null
playing: false
settings: Object
source: HTMLAudioElement
wrapper: HTMLDivElement
__proto__: Object
```

This is how objects are created, but I believe you need to know the plugin well to understand this

```
// Initialize audio js
      audiojs.events.ready(function() {
          var as = audiojs.createAll({


          });
});
```

Comment: Don't try to debug with `alert`. Use `console.log`. Then you can actually see what the object is.

Comment: Would you be able to post the code you're having problems with? Namely the lines where you originally define `as` and the ajax.

Comment: @Paulpro: As long as you're not using IE ^_^

Comment: @Joe added it along with stuff from console log

Comment: @Paulpro Thanks, tried it, gives more info also added it to the question

Comment: @Ilya - please see my answer, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested a working solution. Please note, the code is just to show it works - see my explanation below for specifics.

```
var as;
audiojs.events.ready(function () {
    as = audiojs.createAll();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var mp3 = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/audiojs/02-juicy-r.mp3"; // audio.js example
        // creating new audio element, yours is probably added via ajax
        // [0] used to get DOM element instead of jQuery object.
        var audio = $('<audio/>', {id: 'test'}).appendTo('body').attr('src', mp3)[0];
        var testAS = audiojs.create(audio); // initialise new audio.js player
        as.push(testAS); // add "testAS" object to "as" array of objects
        console.log(as); // log "as" - now holds the original objects + "testAS"
    }, 5000); // timeout used for testing, above code can be in ajax success function instead
});
```

The `mp3` and `audio` variables are just used as a demonstration as I don't know your ajax function's structure.

Audio.js has a `.create()` function which takes a single element as it's argument and returns an object. The original `as` variable is an array containing all the `audio` objects so you can just push the new object onto the end.

By defining `as` outside a function you make it global meaning that everything can access it and any new audio.js objects can be appended.

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for this, but I'm not entirely sure this solves the problem. This will basically add new instances to existing object array right? What I'm trying to figure out is how to replace `var as = audiojs.createAll` with something like `var as = get existing object` So in fact I don't want to create new elements, but use existing one, as I'm required to define **as** again after ajax call, but cant use **createAll** as it just creates new element above previous one. SOrry if I don't make much sense, just can't think of a better way to explain it.

Comment: @Ilya - if you just want to get the original object then use `var as = as;` and make sure you **originally** define `as` outside any function or use `window.as = audiojs.createAll();` in your first audio.js code. If you want you could add the code where you define `as` again?

Comment: Hi, could I please ask you to join this chatroom for more explanation http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31607/audiojs